# VBA Access: Run-time Error '2176'-The setting for this property is too long

Tags: image, vba, ms-access

There is an access database table called `DemoImageT` with a field called `Image` to store images (using OLE Objects).  It has another field called `ID` which is a text field. It has values 1,2,3..etc. I have an Image holder called `ImageBox1` in an Access form. When a button is clicked I want to display the image stored in the table in the image holder on the form. I executed a query and stored the results in a recordset. Then I set the picture property to the retrieved image. My code was:

```
Dim myConnection1 As ADODB.Connection
Dim myRecordSet1 As New ADODB.Recordset
Set myConnection1 = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
Set myRecordSet1.ActiveConnection = myConnection1

myRecordSet1.Open "SELECT * FROM DemoImageT WHERE ID = '1'"

If IsNull(myRecordSet1.Fields(1)) = False Then
  MsgBox ("Image present")
  ImageBox1.Visible = True
  ImageBox1.Picture = myRecordSet1.Fields(1)
Else
  MsgBox ("No image")
End If
```

I get the message box ***Image present***. But then I get:

```
run time error 2176- The setting for this property is too long.
```

The error occurs in the line:

```
Me.ImageBox1.Picture=myRecordSet1.Fields(1)
```

Is there something wrong with the code? Is there any other way to retrieve images stored in  an Access database using VBA and display it on a form? If the above method is correct, what might be wrong?

Comment: what does `myRecordSet1.Fields(1)` actually return?

Comment: @mehow: An image(OLE Object). Can a recordset not hold an image?

Comment: what do you get is you `Debug.print myRecordSet1.Fields(1)`? Do you get a binary for the image? AFAIK, [access can store Ole Objects](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/store-images-in-a-database-HP005280225.aspx).

Comment: Possibly [**THIS**](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B285820) has an answer

Comment: @mehow: When I am debugging I get another run-time error 3705 :'Operation is not allowed when the object is open' in the line myRecordSet1.Open "SELECT * FROM DemoImageT where ID= '1'". But I don't get it when I click the button for which the code is written.

Comment: @mehow: I get the same run-time error 2176 when I click the button in the line ImageBox1.Picture=myRecordSet1.Fields(1). When I debug I get run time error 3705 in open query line itself

Comment: I would guess that `myRecordSet1.Fields(1)` returns a `Field`. `myRecordSet1.Fields(1).Value` should return the contents of that field.

Comment: @Brad: Tried that. Still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a hassle, but you have to write the binary contents of the database field to a temporary file, and set `Me.ImageBox1.Picture` to the path to that file, like this:

```
If IsNull(myRecordSet1.Fields(1)) = False Then
  MsgBox ("Image present")
  ImageBox1.Visible = True
  Module1.BlobToFile myRecordSet1.Fields(1), "c:\temp\temppic.jpg"
  Me.Image1.Picture = "c:\temp\temppic.jpg"
Else
  MsgBox ("No image")
End If
```

Here's the code you need for Module1 that does the actual writing out of the binary data. I cribbed this from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194975/en-us, but I'm putting it here in case MS ever removes it. All you have to do is right-click the Modules folder and select Insert>Module, which will create a new module with the default name of Module1, then paste all code below into there.

```
  Option Explicit

  Const BLOCK_SIZE = 16384

  Sub BlobToFile(fld As ADODB.Field, ByVal FName As String, _
                 Optional FieldSize As Long = -1, _
                 Optional Threshold As Long = 1048576)
  '
  ' Assumes file does not exist
  ' Data cannot exceed approx. 2Gb in size
  '
  Dim F As Long, bData() As Byte, sData As String
    F = FreeFile
    Open FName For Binary As #F
    Select Case fld.Type
      Case adLongVarBinary
        If FieldSize = -1 Then   ' blob field is of unknown size
          WriteFromUnsizedBinary F, fld
        Else                     ' blob field is of known size
          If FieldSize > Threshold Then   ' very large actual data
            WriteFromBinary F, fld, FieldSize
          Else                            ' smallish actual data
            bData = fld.Value
            Put #F, , bData  ' PUT tacks on overhead if use fld.Value
          End If
        End If
      Case adLongVarChar, adLongVarWChar
        If FieldSize = -1 Then
          WriteFromUnsizedText F, fld
        Else
          If FieldSize > Threshold Then
            WriteFromText F, fld, FieldSize
          Else
            sData = fld.Value
            Put #F, , sData  ' PUT tacks on overhead if use fld.Value
          End If
        End If
    End Select
    Close #F
  End Sub

  Sub WriteFromBinary(ByVal F As Long, fld As ADODB.Field, _
                      ByVal FieldSize As Long)
  Dim Data() As Byte, BytesRead As Long
    Do While FieldSize <> BytesRead
      If FieldSize - BytesRead < BLOCK_SIZE Then
        Data = fld.GetChunk(FieldSize - BLOCK_SIZE)
        BytesRead = FieldSize
      Else
        Data = fld.GetChunk(BLOCK_SIZE)
        BytesRead = BytesRead + BLOCK_SIZE
      End If
      Put #F, , Data
    Loop
  End Sub

  Sub WriteFromUnsizedBinary(ByVal F As Long, fld As ADODB.Field)
  Dim Data() As Byte, Temp As Variant
    Do
      Temp = fld.GetChunk(BLOCK_SIZE)
      If IsNull(Temp) Then Exit Do
      Data = Temp
      Put #F, , Data
    Loop While LenB(Temp) = BLOCK_SIZE
  End Sub

  Sub WriteFromText(ByVal F As Long, fld As ADODB.Field, _
                    ByVal FieldSize As Long)
  Dim Data As String, CharsRead As Long
    Do While FieldSize <> CharsRead
      If FieldSize - CharsRead < BLOCK_SIZE Then
        Data = fld.GetChunk(FieldSize - BLOCK_SIZE)
        CharsRead = FieldSize
      Else
        Data = fld.GetChunk(BLOCK_SIZE)
        CharsRead = CharsRead + BLOCK_SIZE
      End If
      Put #F, , Data
    Loop
  End Sub

  Sub WriteFromUnsizedText(ByVal F As Long, fld As ADODB.Field)
  Dim Data As String, Temp As Variant
    Do
      Temp = fld.GetChunk(BLOCK_SIZE)
      If IsNull(Temp) Then Exit Do
      Data = Temp
      Put #F, , Data
    Loop While Len(Temp) = BLOCK_SIZE
  End Sub

  Sub FileToBlob(ByVal FName As String, fld As ADODB.Field, _
                 Optional Threshold As Long = 1048576)
  '
  ' Assumes file exists
  ' Assumes calling routine does the UPDATE
  ' File cannot exceed approx. 2Gb in size
  '
  Dim F As Long, Data() As Byte, FileSize As Long
    F = FreeFile
    Open FName For Binary As #F
    FileSize = LOF(F)
    Select Case fld.Type
      Case adLongVarBinary
        If FileSize > Threshold Then
          ReadToBinary F, fld, FileSize
        Else
          Data = InputB(FileSize, F)
          fld.Value = Data
        End If
      Case adLongVarChar, adLongVarWChar
        If FileSize > Threshold Then
          ReadToText F, fld, FileSize
        Else
          fld.Value = Input(FileSize, F)
        End If
    End Select
    Close #F
  End Sub

  Sub ReadToBinary(ByVal F As Long, fld As ADODB.Field, _
                   ByVal FileSize As Long)
  Dim Data() As Byte, BytesRead As Long
    Do While FileSize <> BytesRead
      If FileSize - BytesRead < BLOCK_SIZE Then
        Data = InputB(FileSize - BytesRead, F)
        BytesRead = FileSize
      Else
        Data = InputB(BLOCK_SIZE, F)
        BytesRead = BytesRead + BLOCK_SIZE
      End If
      fld.AppendChunk Data
    Loop
  End Sub

  Sub ReadToText(ByVal F As Long, fld As ADODB.Field, _
                 ByVal FileSize As Long)
  Dim Data As String, CharsRead As Long
    Do While FileSize <> CharsRead
      If FileSize - CharsRead < BLOCK_SIZE Then
        Data = Input(FileSize - CharsRead, F)
        CharsRead = FileSize
      Else
        Data = Input(BLOCK_SIZE, F)
        CharsRead = CharsRead + BLOCK_SIZE
      End If
      fld.AppendChunk Data
    Loop
  End Sub
```